# The problem with the script for taking coins (Roblox Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a script like this
This is not a local script

```
local folder = workspace.Coins
local players = game:GetService("Players")

function playerSpawned(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = 100
    for i, objects in pairs(folder:GetChildren()) do
        local button = Instance.new("ClickDetector")
        button.Parent = objects
        objects.ClickDetector.CursorIcon = "rbxassetid://7029597423"

        objects.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
            objects.ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 0
            objects.Transparency = 1
            objects.CanCollide = false
            coins.Value = coins.Value + 10
            wait(10)
            objects.ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 300
            objects.Transparency = 0
            objects.CanCollide = true
        end)
    end
end

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(playerSpawned)
```

How do I make it so that if one player takes a coin, the other does not get a coin in the leaderboard?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `for` loop outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

@user15611379 is correct, but their answer is incomplete : you should move the for-loop outside of the function, but you need a way to access the leaderstats of the player that clicks the coin.

A [ClickDetector's MouseClick event](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ClickDetector#MouseClick) can give you the player that interacted with them, so you can use that to access their leaderstats.

```lua
-- define some easy to change values
local DEFAULT_COIN_AMOUNT = 100
local COIN_VALUE = 10
local RESPAWN_TIME = 10


-- when a player joins, create their leaderstats
local players = game:GetService("Players")
function playerSpawned(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = DEFAULT_COIN_AMOUNT
end)
players.PlayerAdded:Connect(playerSpawned)


-- add click detectors to all coins in the world
local folder = workspace.Coins
for _, object in ipairs(folder:GetChildren()) do
    local button = Instance.new("ClickDetector", object)
    button.CursorIcon = "rbxassetid://7029597423"
    button.MouseClick:Connect(function(playerWhoClicked)
        -- hide the coin
        button.MaxActivationDistance = 0
        object.Transparency = 1
        object.CanCollide = false

        -- increase the player's coins counter
        playerWhoClicked.leaderstats.Coins.Value += COIN_VALUE
 
        -- reveal the coin after a short wait
        wait(RESPAWN_TIME)
        object.ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 300
        object.Transparency = 0
        object.CanCollide = true
    end)
end
```